# while doing Response.Redirect on same page my ViewState get Cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

while i redirect the page through Response.Redirect to same URL(to same page) with different Query String my View State get cleared.

Kindly provide me the idea or alternative way to maintain viewstate data of store data somewhere so that after Response.Redirect on same page i can get that value
(for that page only not for new tab)

session will provide me the data through all tabs and pages
i want it to one page only after response.redirect.

Comment: There is difference between Postback and Response.Redirect to same URL(to same page)

Comment: `Response.Redirect` is the same as going to the page for the first time. Your options may be to come up with an alternative to `Response.Redirect`,  using a postback to maintain ViewState. [Server.Transfer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775221/Server-Transfer-VS-Response-Redirect-Simplified) may also be an alternative. I would not be trying to maintain the ViewState as a whole, it is too complex and, by design, hard to manipulate. We don't really have enough information on what you are trying to do, to provide a meaningful answer

Comment: i developed the pure dynamic page.
All the controls and value are filled on the basis of user input
so for each input i am redirecting the page on same URL but with different Query String through Request.QueryString
so i storing the data in ViewState (session is not possible because it create problem if same page is opened multiple times)
so while i redirect using response.redirect than my viewstate get cleared
so i want solution that can maintain data after response.redirect but for that page only

Comment: Session is a viable alternative. Each page instance could have a GUID identifier, this is your session key, This guid can then be passed in the querystring or as a hidden form variable. I still think Server.Transfer could work.

Comment: but i think that GUID identifier is valid one time only
when post back occures than page generate new guid so how can i validate that guid

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect will clear ViewState regardless redirect to same or different page.
If you need to keep ViewState, use partial postback using Ajax mechanism.
If you want to keep ViewState using Response.Redirect, retrieve viewstate and bring it to redirect page using session or query string.

Comment: all control dynamically created so Ajax mechanism not work for me

and the page is pure dynamic so i have to redirect the page again to same URL through response.redirect with different query string

actually i store the flag in viewstate that tell me that page is opened first times only i want to check that the same page can not be opened again by same user if user directly copy and past url string and if we maintain that data in query string than system allows user to open that page again because it get right flag through query string that i don't want 

session also create same issue

Comment: If this is the case, use query string for flag. don't use ViewState. Make sure you do some encryption or something that user unreadable. eg. http://www.blurblur.com?f=vCxcC53W5JHJ7aXjUdDud272e8dd39. Alternatively, work with database to track first time or not.

Comment: User Just make the Duplicate tab by right click on tab

Comment: It's ok. Check in page load

Comment: User Just make the Duplicate tab by right click on tab
in that case when new page is loaded with encrypted format but when i decrypt it i will get same value

i do the entry of page when it open first times in database and store it in viewstate but the problem is that my page is dynamic so it redirect on same url multiple times so when redirection occurs on same page it go and check for entry in database and found that entry of page so i write code that if i found one entry in database then close that page
in this case page must not closed because it is redirected not opened again newly

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously `Response.Redirect` and `PostBack` are two different things. Response.Redirect Clears all the `ViewState` Parameters. If you are not willing to save the value in session I suggest that you send the `Viewstate` data in `Querystring` and on your `PageLoad` check if `Request.Querystring` for that value is not null and if it's not then Save that value in `Viewstate` again.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
    {
          if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
          {
                  ViewState["id"]=Request.QueryString["id"];
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i store the flag in viewstate that tell me that page is opened first times only

and the page is pure dynamic so i have to redirect the page again to same URL through response.redirect with different query string

i want to check that the same page can not be opened again by same user if user directly copy and past url string and if we maintain that data in query string than system allows user to open that page again because it get right flag through query string that i don't want